# Which is harder to compute: $\pi_{n+k}$ or $\Omega^{fr}_n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Denote the $n+k$-th homotopy group of $S^n$ by $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ and the group of framed cobordism classes by $\Omega_n^{fr}(S^k)$. A central problem of algebraic topology is to compute $\pi_i(S^j)$ for all $i,j$. Pontryagin established that $\Omega_n^{fr}$ and  $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ are isomorphic. Assuming that $\Omega_n^{fr}(S^k)$ are easier to compute than $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ this is a big leap of progress.

But then on Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Framed_cobordism)) I found:

In more recent work the argument is usually reversed, with cobordism groups computed in terms of homotopy groups (Scorpan 2005).

Which raises the following question: which of the two is easier to calculate? Or are both difficult depending on $n$ and $k$?

Comment: They're isomorphic groups so technically they're equally difficult to compute.  Aside from a few very low-dimensional cases, people always compute these via $\pi_{n+k} S^n$ and they avoid $\Omega^{fr}_n$ for all purposes except giving geometric intuition behind some of the constructions, like the J-homomorphism.

Comment: @RyanBudney Is it the case that for $k=1,2$ the $\Omega_k^{fr}$ are easier to calculate than the $\pi_{n+k}S^n$?

Comment: I personally see them as about equally difficult.  I think it's a good exercise to go through each computation and compare them.  For example, $\Omega^{fr}_1$ is co-dimension one manifolds.  The Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem tells you these manifold are the boundary of a co-dimension 0 manifold, which gives you a proof that the framed cobordism group is trivial.  Alternatively $\pi_{k+1}S^1$ is trivial since the universal cover of $S^1$ is contractible.

Comment: @RyanBudney I was asking this because I thought Pontryagin's 1950 paper "Homotopy classification of the mappings of an $(n+2)$-sphere on an $n$-dimensional one" was the first progress towards determining $\pi_{n+2}(S^n)$. But that would only be true if $\Omega^{fr}_{2}$ were computable while $\pi_{n+2}(S^n)$ aren't. In this case: does his paper add nothing but a (good) geometric intuition?

Comment: In a sense you are right.  Pontriagin's paper came before Postnikov systems and Serre's dissertation, so there were no "in-roads" at the time to compute homotopy groups of spheres from the algebraic perspective.  But that rapidly changed after Serre's Ph.D. Co-dimension two is only reasonable from the manifolds perspective since surfaces are manageably-computable.